# the analysis of my $file = ${$chainro->{$ro}->{$id}}[$i];

Tags: perl

I have a two level hash `%chainro` , each key of `$chainro{$ro}{$id}`points to an array. The following code is to iterate through the first level of hash, `$chainro->{$ro}`. I can guess what 
does `my $file = ${$chainro->{$ro}->$id}}[$i];`  aim to perform. However, I do not know why `${$chainro->{$ro}->{$id}}`was written this way? In specific, why do we need to add ${ } to wrap the `$chainro->${ro}->{$id}`

```
foreach my $id (keys %{$chainro->{$ro}})
{
   $size = $#{$chainro->{$ro}->{$id}};
   for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
   {
     my $file = ${$chainro->{$ro}->{$id}}[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: See: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
${ EXPR1 }[ EXPR2 ]
```

is an alternate way of writing

```
EXPR1->[ EXPR2 ]
```

so

```
${ $chainro->{$ro}->{$id} }[$i]
```

can be written as

```
$chainro->{$ro}->{$id}->[$i]
```

or even as

```
$chainro->{$ro}{$id}[$i]
```

---

Cleaned up:

```
for my $id (keys %{ $chainro->{$ro} }) {
   my $files = $chainro->{$ro}{$id};
   for my $i (0..$#$files) {
      my $file = $files->[$i];
      ...
   }
}
```

Or if you don't need `$i`:

```
for my $id (keys %{ $chainro->{$ro} }) {
   my $files = $chainro->{$ro}{$id};
   for my $file (@$files) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is  to dereference a reference to something.
The something is an array here.